# Why does storing an element in a list at position 0 copy the element to position -1 also?

Tags: python, list

If I create a list like this

```
list = [10]
```

then 10 gets stored at `list[0]`, 10 also gets stored at `list[-1]`!

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because for a list of length 1, index -1 **is the same item** as index 0.

Negative indices are interpreted as counting from the end; they are translated to `len(listobject) - givenindex`. For your sample list, length 1 minus 1 is index 0.

Similarly, for a list of length 2, `-1` is the same item as index 1, and -2 is the same as index 0.

Perhaps this is best illustrated with a little table; here the list length is 5:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| h | e | l | l | o |  # contents
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |  # indices
+---+---+---+---+---+
|-5 |-4 |-3 |-2 |-1 |  # negative indices
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

You can access the `e` in this list both as index 1 and index -4.